# Is there cases where interpolation is impossible?

Tags: interpolation

I just learned interpolation and have been looking through it.

It seems like for every data set, interpolation is possible -- is this true? Is there any cases it is not possible to use interpolation?

Any hints or help on this question will greatly help!!!

Comment: You might be interested in the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the data set $x_0 = 0$, $y_0 = 0$, $x_1 = 0$, $y_1 = 1$. No function can serve as the interpolation here.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know the [tangent function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#tan)?

You have $\tan 0 = 0$ and $\tan \pi = 0$. Dare to interpolate for $\frac\pi 2$...?